# Core Data fetched data is deleted when app terminates / gets killed

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration

I have a weird issue going on with an app which uses Core Data. It creates and stores data ok, but when it gets killed or terminates, then the data doesn't appear anymore. Sometimes appears in chunks of data (if there were 10 objects, only 1 or 2 appear later).

My Core Data stack is organized this way: http://martiancraft.com/blog/2015/03/core-data-stack/

Also, this only happens when running a Testflight build using a AppStore provisioning profile. When I run the app in the device using XCode, it works OK.

The way I'm fetching data is the follow:

```
NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Organization" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[request setEntity:entityDescription];

NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"priority" ascending:NO];
[request setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

NSError *error;
_fetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request managedObjectContext:moc sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:nil];
_fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

if (![_fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    abort();
}
```

I would truly appreciate some help.

Comment: I'm suspecting that your issue is more in the manner in which you save data, rather than how you fetch it. Zarra's approach to persistence uses two contexts that may or may not have completed by the time your app terminates. So do you `performBlockAndWait`, or ensure this process completes in the background if incomplete at the time your app terminates? Have you investigated using app delegate protocol methods to complete processes before your app terminates etc?

Answer (score 0):

If you are crashing and saving rarely that is going to cause you issues.  Either stop the crashes (best approach) or save more often (bandaid).